# Manually installed Visual Studio Code extension not showing up on remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I have been using the LLVM project's `lldb-vscode` extension locally on my Ubuntu box for quite some time successfully. I followed the [steps at the README](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/lldb/tools/lldb-vscode) and it works flawlessly. It involves copying both `lldb-server` and `lldb-vscode` binaries plus the provided `package.json` file into the proper locations under `$HOME/.vscode/extensions`.

But when I open Visual Studio Code on my laptop and open (remotely) the same project I was debugging successfully on the Ubuntu box, the extension does not appear and I cannot debug. The debug configuration type "lldb-vscode" now shows up with red squiggles underneath. The message says "The debug type is not recognized".

I suspect the "$HOME/.vscode" folder is not scanned by vscode when working from a remote.

So the questions are:

1. Am I goofing somewhere?
2. How to enable this extension remotely?

Comment: Only the original developers can tell. Don't waste time elsewhere, and go back to raise an issue, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue is very simple.

Local user extensions are installed at "$HOME/.vscode" and remote extensions are installed on "$HOME/.vscode-server/extensions".

It was just a matter of creating a softlink from the later to the former as in

```bash
$ cd ~/.vscode-server/extensions
$ ln -s ~/.vscode/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0 llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0
$ ls -1
 llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0 -> /home/fred/.vscode/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0
 ms-vscode.cpptools-1.12.4-linux-x64
```

UPDATE 10/10/2022: An issue has been [created on Github](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58252) and a [documentation patch has been submitted](https://reviews.llvm.org/D135577) to LLVM to alert new users.